# Check custom validation in RSpec that is run only on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

I have a custom validation that is run on create:

```
validate :validate_emails, if: :send_email, on: :create
```

In my spec I do this:

```
describe "#validate_emails" do
  let(:box_shared_link_2) { BoxSharedLink.new(box_file, link_type: "view", email: "john@doe.com jane@doe.com;johny@doe.com") }
  let(:invalid_box_shared_link) { BoxSharedLink.new(box_file, link_type: "view", email: "john jane;johny@doe.com", send_email: "Update and Send Link") }

  it "should be invalid" do
    expect(invalid_box_shared_link).to_not be_valid
  end

  it "should be valid" do
    expect(box_shared_link_2).to be_valid
  end
end
```

How can I tell RSpec to to run the validation on create? Thanks

Comment: i think you just need to save those objects before the expectations, like `invalid_box_shared_link.save; expect(invalid_box_shared_link).to_not be_valid`

Answer (score 1):

Super old question, but @Greg's answer kind of led me in the right direction. He said that `be_valid` just calls `valid?`, and `valid?` accepts a context which can  be used to specify which callbacks to test against, ex: `valid?(:create)`. Similarly, `be_valid` passes the args through as a context to `valid?`, so one can just do `be_valid(:create)` to run against validations that run `on: :create`. So I recommend changing the test in question to:

```rb
  it "should be invalid" do
    expect(invalid_box_shared_link).to_not be_valid(:create)
  end

  it "should be valid" do
    expect(box_shared_link_2).to be_valid(:create)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably know this, but the `be_foo` matcher calls `foo?` method and check it's truthfulness, so

```rb
  it "should be invalid" do
    expect(invalid_box_shared_link).to_not be_valid
  end
```

would only call `valid?`, and since it will not trigger the creation of the object - your validation will not be triggered.

What you need to do is something like:

```rb
  it "should be invalid" do
    expect(invalid_box_shared_link.save).to eq(false) # saving failed
    expect(invalid_box_shared_ling.errors).not_to be_empty # saving failed because of validation errors
    # you might also want to check the actual error, like
    expect(invalid_box_shared_ling.errors).to include(emails: 'validation error message') # I'm guessing what actually the array would include
  end
```